# Are there conditions for which the Pareto distribution arises? Are there characterization theorems of the Pareto distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, pareto-distribution

There are many real-world phenomena in which a variable of a population follows the Pareto distribution. I am wondering, what are the *sufficient conditions* for the distribution to be Pareto? And if it is possible to go further, what are the *necessary and sufficient conditions?*

I am wondering if there is anything analogous to the central limit theorem, which explains how and why the normal distribution arises when we consider sample means for sampling with replacement. Granted, the Pareto distribution commonly applies to populations (if I'm not mistaken), so my analogy is not perfect, but I hope my point is communicated nonetheless.

To put it shortly, is there a characterization theorem that explains why this distribution tends to be so naturally occurring? Even better, how can I reasonably tell ahead of time when and when not something is going to follow the Pareto distribution?

Answer (score 2):

There has been some research pertaining to the topic concerned during the $70$s.

$\rm [I]$ provides such characterization taking motivation from the Pareto law. Heuristic though it may be, it is intuitive:

Let there be a tax exempt level $m, $ the actual income be $X$ and the reported income be $Y.$ Let the under reportage be $U.$ Anyone would tend to under-report if $X> m. $ So, $$Y= X-U, ~U\in(0, \max\{0, X-m\}). \tag 1\label 1$$

It is easy to infer from $\eqref 1$ that $Y> m$ when $X> m. $

Assume the expected amount of under-reporting to be proportional to $X-m, ~X> m, $ i.e. $$\mathbb E[U\mid X=x] = b(x-m) := a+bx.\tag 2\label 2$$

Let the reported income $Y=y.$

***Theorem**: If $\eqref 1,~\eqref 2$ hold, then the necessary and sufficient condition for $X$ to follow Pareto distribution with a finite mean is $$\mathbb E[U\mid X> y]=\alpha +\beta y, ~~ \beta >b> 0.\tag 3\label 3$$*

The theorem is easy to prove: show the distribution $G(\cdot)=1-F(\cdot)$ which satisfies $\eqref 3$ that is, $$\frac{1}{G(y) }\int_y^\infty (a+bx) ~\mathrm dF(x) =\alpha + \beta x, ~~y> m\tag 4\label 4$$ is that of Pareto. $F$ is continuous as any possible point of discontinuity would be at $(a-\alpha) /(\beta-b) $ which follows from $\eqref 4$ but again from the same equation, $a+by\leq \alpha +\beta y$ from which $y> m\geq (a-\alpha) /(\beta-b) .$

Finally, define $H(y) := \int_y^\infty G(x) ~\mathrm dx. $ Solve $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \ln H(y) = \frac{-b}{\alpha -a+(\beta-b)y}\tag 5\label 5$$ to deduce $H(\cdot)$ and hence $G(\cdot)=-H^\prime(\cdot),~\eqref 5$  follows from $\eqref 4$ using integration by parts.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ A Characterization of the Pareto Distribution, *Nagesh S. Revankar, Michael J. Hartley, Marcello Pagano,* Ann. Statist. $2(3): 599-601 $(May, $1974$). DOI: $10.1214/\text{aos}/1176342723.$